# Is it possible to declare a variable's data type before initializing it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) as of October 11, 2017 states the following:

> JavaScript is a *loosely typed* or a *dynamic* language. That means you don't have to declare the type of a variable ahead of time. The type will get determined automatically while the program is being processed.

This means, among other things, that we can write less code because JS automatically detects the data type when a variable is initialized. For example:

```
let amount = 0;  // since 0 is a number, this variable is of type "number"
amount += 1;  // which makes it real easy to add another number to it

console.log(amount);  // returns 1
```

After doing some research, though, I think it may be more accurate to revise the second sentence to read:

> That means you cannot declare the type of variable ahead of time.

For example:

```
let amount;  // without initialization, this variable is of type "undefined"
amount += 1;  // which makes it impossible to add a number to it

console.log(amount);  // returns NaN
```

If there is a way to declare a variable's data type before it is initialized, please provide details in your answer.

Comment: Variables in JavaScript **don't have types**.  *Values* have types, and a variable can be assigned a value of any type regardless of the type of its current value.

Comment: Even if JS was statically typed, that wouldn't necessarily mean that there's a default initialization. What is the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: @llama, curiosity mostly. The documentation implies that we have a choice.

Comment: @samurai_jane I've made a couple of edits to that MDN document as it's clearly misleading. Unfortunately many of the tutorial-type documents at MDN have similar questionable content, much as I like MDN overall.

Answer (score 3):

Is not possible to declare the type of a variable in plain Javascript, not even in the latest specification (ES7). There is no static type checking either.

The behavior you observe here:

```
let amount;
amount += 1;
console.log(amount);
```

... is due to `undefined + 1` evaluating to `NaN`, which may or may not make sense, but is the way JS works.

You may reassign a variable with any type:

```
let a = 1;
a = 'asdf';
console.log(b);
```

Some projects like [Flow](https://flow.org/) and [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) bring static type checking to Javascript.